# tms-NET sampling in Python

Tags: python, random, statistics, sampling

I have been trying find some pre-implementation of tms-NET sampling in python (as I couldn't implement by myself) for my projects wherein I want to perform sampling on numpy array of shape (num_of_data, embedding_dimensions=100). I couldn't find it.

Can anyone help me with my problem ?

I also try using Latin Hypercube Sampling however the scale of my data in my numpy array is not the with the value sample by pyDOE2 implementation of LHS.

```
from pyDOE2 import lhs

num_samples = X.shape[0]
num_dimensions = X.shape[1] # 100

lhs_samples = lhs(num_dimensions, samples=5)
```

The X array has values range from 0 to 1000 while most of the value samples by lhs is around 0.

Additionally, the description of my projects stats that

"If the size of the remaining X is equal to zero, then the selected train sample represents the complete data, and it is considered to be good. Otherwise, the data points are sampled from the remaining X using (t,m,s)-Nets. The samples which are selected using (t,m,s)-Nets are appended to the train sample for improving the representativeness of the data. "

I am not sure if my approach is correct.

If anyone could help, I would be very glad for it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to fully understand all your questions. I do not know pyODE2, and not sure what X should represent, especially with the "size of remaining X" part. But the thing I can do, is point out where you would find working implementation of qmc sampling scheme.

- You have the scipy qmc submodule which contains multiple sampling scheme https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.qmc.html
- You also have the following library, although it requires much more effort imho : https://github.com/QMCSoftware/QMCSoftware
- Finally, you have UTK : https://utk-team.github.io/utk/. The library has a python binding, but it requires you to compile it
  by yourself (DISCLAMER: I am one of the main contributors of this library).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35752521)

Comment: I understand that, but how am I suppose to answer questions in the form : "where can I find functions that does XXX or YYY". Am I suppose to answer "in stackoverflow, here are the hundreds of lines of codes that does what you want" and copy-paste library codes ? There are reasons the code he asks for is not traditionally implemented in Python but only available through bindings...